# percentage boost in a correlated value

Tags: correlation, causality

In a psychology article I read that: “modesty predicted increased emotional intelligence (. = .43, CI [.35, .51]), which predicted self-esteem (. = .55, CI [.46, .63]), and in turn predicted greater subjective well-being.” This finding suggests that modesty can boost emotional intelligence and self-esteem, leading to increased well-being and lower susceptibility to depression.

My questions are: how much of a percentage boost in emotional intelligence does a ten percent boost in modesty lead to (with correlation = .43)? What is the formula for this kind of question?

[Modesty promotes well-being through increased emotional intelligence and self-esteem](https://www.psypost.org/2020/06/modesty-promotes-well-being-through-increased-emotional-intelligence-and-self-esteem-57125)

Comment: A fast view indicates that these authors overstate their conclusions. They have a correlational study (internet questionnaire, not some experiment) but they suggest causal conclusions ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this question using linear regression which used Pearson's r, the means and standard deviations of the two factors. The inputs for the linear regression can be found in the study.

The equations for the linear regression can be found [here](http://sites.utexas.edu/sos/guided/inferential/numeric/bivariate/cor/), showing the relationship between Pearson's r and linear regression.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Please add a reference for your link so that one knows what it is, and can found the resource in the future if the link dies